# Paralleling Power Supplies

Tags: power, ldo, linear, switching

I was just curious. Can one parallel Linear Regulators, LDOs or Switching Power Supply ICs in order to increase total possible power output? By parallel I mean tie V<sub>in</sub> to the same rail and V<sub>out</sub> to the same rail and duplicate any supporting circuitry (feedback networks, caps etc.).

Comment: Usually yes however this does not mean each will provide the same current.  You may find that because one device has a nominally identical but in practice higher voltage output it will provide all the current until it goes into current limit and only then will the second device start to conduct.  You need to take this into account when considering cooling.

Comment: Usually no, except for power supplies specifically specified for *current sharing* operation.  Some switchers actually have a current sharing line for that purpose.  If not designed for this, you may get various types of instability of the whole system.  Each supply feeding the same line thru a separate diode is usually safe, direct-tie is a bad idea without a deliberate spec.

Comment: With LDOs, I have implemented parallel circuits before and it works fine, but I am not about DC DC Converters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. The problem is picking a system that causes the regulators to share the current more-or-less equally, given that they won't have precisely the same output voltage as a result of component tolerances, etc.

On approach that works on many circuits is to simply include a small-value resistor in series with each output. Obviously, the drawback is that this increases the effective source impedance of the regulators, reducing the precision of the regulation.

Some regulators (and regulator controller chips) have explicit support for load sharing. See their datasheets for the specific details.

Answer (score 3):

There are some switching power supply chips you can parallel because, provided one chip is master and the other is PWM slave, both sets of power transistors switch on and off together and there is no fight, just twice the amps. The [TPS40180](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps40180.pdf) is an example that specifically describes how to parallel up devices. TI seem to have a few like this although I've never noticed Linear Tech offering exactly the same functionality.

Linear power supplies chips like 7805 can be paralleled (without a scrap/fight) but usually one does all the work and overheats then goes and sulks while the other takes over - not an ideal result but no smoke is the main thing.